# pass values from textbox to url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i pass values from textbox to a url on click of a button using javascript? I have a login page. when i input a username and password in a textbox, the url should take the values and give the response. How can i do it?

```
http://url.php?id=login&email=<email>&password=<password>
```

This url gives response as `{"status":0,"msg":"Email is Wrong!"}` and  when i put my id and pwd in url

```
http://url.php?id=login&email=abc@gmail.com&password=abc
```

url give response as

```
{"status":1,"msg":"Session is active","session_id":"p246igeaadcdui7hb0o2677c53","user_id":"13"}
```

Thanks in advance..

function A() {
        $.getJSON('http:url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) {
            alert(data.status);
            alert(data.msg);


        });
    }

    function B() {
        $.getJSON('url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) {
            alert(data.user_id);
            document.getElementById("login").innerHTML;
        });

    }

Username : 
Password :

This is what i am working on

Comment: You might want to reconsider putting the user's password in the URL in plaintext like that...

Comment: no i want the value to pass from text to the url as i click on a button

Comment: Yes, which means your user's email will be visible in the URL in plain text. That's a Bad Thing.

Comment: no actually right now i am working on local server. so its only for my coding.

Comment: @SONALKASLIWAL Don't ever do that. Eventually, by accident, you might just decide to use this solution in production code.

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript:

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password ").value;
var url = "http://url.php?id=login&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password);
window.location.href = url;
```

jQuery:

```
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var url = "http://url.php?id=login&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(password);
window.location.href = url;
```

Note that for my example to work, the email and the password input fields must have the id set to email and password respectively.

Comment: This one does not pass the var url to address bar?

Comment: what do you mean by "must have the id set to email and password respectively."

Comment: @jurka It doesn't pass it to the address bar, right. Just add `window.location.href = url;` (edited the question)

Comment: @SONALKASLIWAL I mean `<input type="text" id="email" /> <input type="password" id="password />`

Comment: function A() { $.getJSON('http:url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) { alert(data.status); alert(data.msg); }); } function B() { $.getJSON('url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) { alert(data.user_id); document.getElementById("login").innerHTML; }); }

Comment: can you suggest something now?

Answer (score 0):

ajax version:

```
//same as satoshi version
var myUrl = "http://url.php?id=login&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+"& password="+encodeURIComponent(password);

$.ajax({
    url : myUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        alert( data.status ? ("logged in " + data.msg) : ("error: " + data.msg));
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: function A() { $.getJSON('http:url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) { alert(data.status); alert(data.msg); }); } function B() { $.getJSON('url.php?id=login&email=&password=', function (data) { alert(data.user_id); document.getElementById("login").innerHTML; }); }